# How many more years until AI replaces all programming jobs?

Tags: computer-programming, software-development

I'm curious to know from those who have a clear understanding of both

1. AI
2. the software development process

How many years until software engineers, developers and programmers are no longer needed in the workforce because AI can do their jobs sufficiently well? And produce whatever is needed in the market?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this will ever happen, we do not have true AI (or AGI), current models are just parroting the training set code. they do not really analyze or think about code over human capabilities.

There are also huge ethical and legal issues about AI systems for code, since they were trained on large datasets of open source software, with different licenses, and again models do not output licenses for their code, so you cannot use it commercially.

Not even humans know how to make software properly, there are huge issues in terms of scalability, proper software development practices, and integration with other systems. Current AI models do not know anything about this.

So nobody can tell you how many years left, because it is an event that nobody knows if will ever happen, same for autonomous driving, it is always "[two years away](https://futurism.com/video-elon-musk-promising-self-driving-cars)".

Answer (score 0):

Having tried out Chat GPT and Github auto pilot recently to help with game engine programming in C++ I was not impressed, it produced terrible code. Honestly, it is hard to say really. It could be a possibility way in the future much like prompting today, that humans create or use an existing logical language like https://www.lojban.org/mw-redir.html lojban here to communicate with machines better, so rather than programming them we bring them into society through communication and such much similar to the likes of bringing up a child, that then AI entity would be added to other entities. Possibly, it could more complicated as well if humans were to be enthused with something like neuralink in the future, would humans need programming also? But overall I agree with the similar answer, it is always two years away or something like that, there's too many questions at the moment and not enough answers to say for sure.